# Floating point rounding (in java)

Tags: java, floating-point, rounding

What is the best way of determining if a given float(or double) has no significant decimal places.

```
f(234.0)  = true
f(34.45)  = false
f(3.1322) = false
```

i.e. equivalent of

`EQ(((int)number) * 1.0 , number)`

where EQ is a given method to compare floating points and it is OK to assume that the float fits in an integer.

Comment: Is your first name Josh by any chance ?

Answer (score 2):

`Math.rint(x) == x`

[`Math.rint()`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#rint(double)) returns a `double`, so it also works for large numbers where the `long` result of `Math.round()` overflows.

Note that this also gives true for positive and negative infinity. You can explicitly exclude them by `Math.rint(x) == x && !Double.isInfinite(x)`.

Comment: +1 for using `rint` rather than any other method of rounding to integer.  Since this rounds to the *nearest* integer, it doesn't generally require an FPU rounding mode change (which can be surprisingly slow).  [Though I believe that this is less of an issue these days, thanks to the SSE instructions in newer x86/x64 processors.]

Answer (score 1):

Round the value to the nearest integer, and calculate the absolute difference to the actual value.

If that difference is less than a certain percentage of the actual value you are close "enough".

Comment: Hi Thor, I was hoping for a solution which avoids the cast. Could some jugglery be done with Float.floatToRawIntBits() etc. which is more efficient than this?

Comment: 'MicroBenchmarking' is difficult, isn't it? And I thought regular profilers would be useless here(?)

Comment: If you cannot measure it, don't do it.  Readability is more important.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
public static boolean f(double d) {
    return d % 1 == 0;
}
```